# Software Center doesn't find apache, php

Tags: software-installation

I have installed elementary os, based on 14.04.

It's totally strange: I cannot find apache or php in the Software Center or via `apt-get install apache`.

All repositories are checked. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
apt-cache search apache
```

The name of package is apache2, so you may try

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: ah, thanks. I'm not totally sure, but the search field before 14.04 accepted the term 'apache' for successfully finding apache2.